# Network GUI Tools in 11.10+ (Whois, DNS Checker, Trace Route, etc...)

Tags: 11.10, networking

In older versions of Ubuntu there was this "Network Gui" program that had a whois option, Tracing, pinging and all the terminal commands for network but in GUI. If I can recall, I think it was before Unity came to play, maybe before 11.04. How can I, using 11.10 with Unity (Do not want to use Gnome2 or Gnome3, just Unity), get to this Network swiss army program or what package installs this program.

Comment: Do you mean Network Administration Tool ?

Comment: Sorry LnxSlck I do not remember the actual name but I know it was a program that had several network options.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The package is called `gnome-nettool` and can (if not already) be installed via the terminal or the Ubuntu Software Center.

Look for it on the Unity dash

[image]

Hope this is the one your looking for

[image]

Comment: OMG yeah It was that one. I can't believe I didn't type network in Dash. I was typing whois and stuff like that. I may be ill in the head.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically about the **WHOIS** tool, so far I haven't been able to find a good enough GUI WHOIS tool for GNU/Linux (tried [Greenwich](http://freecode.com/projects/greenwich) but it's too limited for my needs), thus I keep using the online WHOIS service [DomainTools](http://whois.domaintools.com), instead of any local graphical or command-line application and/or set of tools.

For the other services, I use the **gnome-nettool** package.

**[update]**: I've been using a free online WHOIS service named **[MYIP.MS](http://myip.ms)** and so far I'm very satisfied