# Graphical applications / ports / tasks manager?

Tags: 16.04, application-development, monitor

I'm trying to manage my running applications for each port on Ubuntu (monitoring).

Any suggestions for a graphical interface?

Comment: Please explain in more detail what it is you want to do.

Comment: I'd like to monitor my running application on my Ubuntu server. For kind of health-validation.

Comment: Assuming you're aware of `netstat` and other tools and strictly want a GUI for this? - https://askubuntu.com/questions/333921/list-all-internet-connections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used this particular tool but googling for `netstat gui` turned it up. It's called [Net Activity Viewer](http://netactview.sourceforge.net/).

*View when system's at rest*

[image: ss#1]

*View when system's being used to browse internet*

[image: ss#2]

Alternatively there's GNOME Network Tool (gnome-nettool) which is covered here - [Network GUI Tools in 11.10+ (Whois, DNS Checker, Trace Route, etc...)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/112403/network-gui-tools-in-11-10-whois-dns-checker-trace-route-etc).

#### References

- [Downloading & Installing](http://netactview.sourceforge.net/download.html)